# Recognize a touch for a UIView that is only created at the moment that touch occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uianimation

I created a "slide view" (a `UIView` subclass) which animates on screen by dragging it up. The animation and everything else related to the animation works perfectly fine. This question targets only the very first touch on the screen when the slide view itself will be initialized:

The slide view itself uses the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`to recognize touches. The thing is, my slide view will be initialized only at the time when the user touches down a UIButton. Parts of the slide view are initially locates on that button, so that when the user touches that button, the touch is also located inside the slide view's frame.

I only want to create the view at the time the touch occurs, because the view is pretty heavy. I don't want to waste resources cause often the button is not even used.

**How can I make the slide view recognize that first touch that also initializes (and adds it as a subview to super) the slide view itself?**

Comment: You are saying your slide view has pangestures then you also want to detect a single tap on that slide view right ?

Comment: @ChinabS. Yeah, that is correct. Is that wrong? The gesture works at least

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out for more details:
[Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html)

Well and you can add both gesture pan as well as tap gesture. It will definitely work as tap is not the first action of the pan gesture. So no need to wait for tap gesture to fail.

In short you can add both gestures and handle them simply.

Comment: I am struggling with your answer: Are you saying I should use both gestures at the same time or should I change the gesture to use tab gesture? can you give me some more details? thx.

Comment: Absolutely you should use both the gestures on your slideview.